# Object is represented by "0 key/value pairs", not memory address within LLVM

Tags: objective-c, xcode, llvm

I've got simple class:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface FlurryDelegate : NSObject

@property(assign, atomic) BOOL isWelcomeScreenActionStarted;
@property(assign, atomic) BOOL isJamSessionScreenOpened;
@property(assign, atomic) BOOL isMetadataTransferStarted;

/*
  some instance and class methods
*/
@end
```

I would like in debugger value of this fields but when I make breakpoint I receive object but "0 key/value pairs". What can be a problem?

My code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoadAndJamSessionIsNotNil {
    flurryDelegate = [[FlurryDelegate alloc] init];
    [flurryDelegate logUser:self.api.userAccount openJamSession:self.jamSession action:@"New jam session was opened"]; //breakpoint here
/* some code */
}
```

Debugger:
[image: Screenshot from debuger]

Comment: What happens when you open `self`? Do you see the underlying property variables?

Comment: Few things that may help: try to clean and rebuild your project. And make sure you're running debug configuration, not release.

Comment: @What happens when you open self? Do you see the underlying property variables?
yes, there are properties and also flurryDelegate

clean and rebuild didn't help

Comment: @TomaszChabinka did you resolve this issue? i have same problem too

Comment: No, but as far as I remember you can still have access to fields of objects by LLVM console. You need (as far as I remember) to use "p something" to log value of something, e.g. "p [self class]"

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I was having this exact same issue! I have a very simple class and it was like Xcode thought it was a dictionary.

Quitting Xcode and relaunching it fixed the issue for me.

Comment: I had the exact same problem, after quitting Xcode and relaunching my NSObject was now a true object instead of a NSDictionary with 0 key/value pairs. PS. you NEED to quit it cleaning, the project is NOT enough :(

Answer (score 0):

IF you point some var to NSDictionary instead of your interface class and build the project, the Xcode will treat your class as NSDictionary for [super init]. So delete the wrong code, clean the project and Restart Xcode.