# I made a new Class, but why it doesn't keep the values inside of object instance?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, class

I created the class Player.h as model.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class Player;

@interface Player : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber * score;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate   * datetime;

-(id)initWithDictionary:(NSMutableDictionary *)dic;

@end
```

Here is the Player.m

```
#import "Player.h"

@implementation Player

-(id)initWithDictionary:(NSMutableDictionary *)dic {

    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        self.name = [dic objectForKey:@"name"];
        self.score = [dic objectForKey:@"score"];
        self.datetime = [dic objectForKey:@"datetime"];
    }
    return self;

}


-(id)init {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        self.name = @"";
        self.score = @-1;
        self.datetime = [NSDate date];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Using the class:

Adding some breakpoints, when I try to see the variable content on Variables View, it shows 0 items on object, where should have some values inside of it.

```
Player * player = [[Player alloc] init];
player.name = @"Billy";
player.score = @100;
player.datetime = [NSDate date];

NSLog(@"Name:%@ Score:%@ DateTime:%@", player.name, player.score, player.datetime);
```

[Breakpoint stop one - see the init is fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyCLZ.png)

[When try to set anything, it says : 0 keys/values pairs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Me38s.png)

I can't understand this behavior, any ideas 0 keys?

Sorry, my level here in stackoverflow doesn't allow me to share more links images.
**UPDATED:**
Issue working around.
I just closed the Xcode, cleaned project, deleted derived data and now is working fine... The reason... another mistery of xcode... ;)
If someone has a reason of this behavior, please let us know!

Comment: The code needs to be in the question, add it to the question.

Comment: Here you may find someone with the same problem, I hope this could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26782469/object-is-represented-by-0-key-value-pairs-not-memory-address-within-llvm [![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/iP6PC.png)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/iP6PC.png)
[![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/SMQKy.png)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/SMQKy.png)

Comment: What does "why it doesn't keep the values inside of object instance?" mean? Additional information needs to be provided to make the question clear.

Comment: Pay attention on the screenshots, specially where the breakpoints are. See 0Keys/values pairs?

Comment: Thank you for your tip! I just close the Xcode, clean project, delete derived data and now is working fine... The reason... another mistery of xcode... ;)

Comment: He may not describe it terribly well, but the OP is reporting a legitimate problem with Xcode. It's showing a description of a custom object as if it's a dictionary, which it's not. I don't think it deserves a down-vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Showing your Player object with the description "0 key value pairs" is wrong. Xcode seems to be confused and think your object is a dictionary. The suggestions on the other thread say to either restart Xcode, clean and rebuild your project, or both. I would try those things.

As others have said, you have your breakpoint on the line where you are assigning a value to your player's `name` property. The debugger stops your program BEFORE the statement is executed. not after, so `name`won't be set yet. Try putting your breakpoint further down, and then typing commands into the debugger console like `evaluate self.name` (`e self.name` for short). Those of us who learned Xcode's debugger when it was GDB will be in the habit of using `print` (`p` for short) or `po` (which is short for print-object. The `po` abbreviation maps to `evaluate` in GDB, but the long form of `print-object isn't valid any more.)

Answer (score 2):

The breakpoint you set is stopping the code before the line you break on, not after.

If you step over the code (the arrow at a right angle) you should see the result of `player.name = playerName`

Comment: I did, but couldn't upload the image to here due the limits of my account on Stackoverflow...